# Numpy and Matlab difference in sum?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

I have a code that I am trying to translate from Matlab to Python however there is a problem with summation:

```
a=np.arange(1,28).reshape(3,3,3)
print a
print np.sum(np.sum(a,axis=1),axis=2)
```

gives me `axis index out of bound error`. According to the answer below I am updating this example.  The result for:

```
a=np.arange(1,28).reshape(3,3,3)
print a
print np.sum(np.sum(a,axis=1),axis=2)
```

is:

```
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6]
  [ 7  8  9]]

 [[10 11 12]
  [13 14 15]
  [16 17 18]]

 [[19 20 21]
  [22 23 24]
  [25 26 27]]]
[ 45 126 207]
```

but the same code in Matlab works fine:

```
a=1:27
b=reshape(a,[3,3,3])
b(:,:,1)=b(:,:,1)';
b(:,:,2)=b(:,:,2)';
b(:,:,3)=b(:,:,3)';
b
sum(sum(b,2),3)
```

Will give the following output:
What is the problem?

```
b(:,:,1) =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9


b(:,:,2) =

    10    11    12
    13    14    15
    16    17    18


b(:,:,3) =

    19    20    21
    22    23    24
    25    26    27

ans =

        99
       126
       153
```

Comment: Note that `a` and `b` don't have the same alignment.  `a[0,1,2] == 6`, but `b(1,2,3) == 20`.

Comment: @DSM, thank you, but what should I do exactly to make them become in the same alignment?

Comment: I think you'll get the same array if you do `a=1:27;b=reshape(a,[3,3,3])` in Matlab and `a=np.arange(1,28).reshape(3,3,3,order='F')` in `numpy`.  Alternatively you could use `permute` or `.transpose` to fix it after the fact.  Depends on what indexing convention you prefer.  Also note that you can sum over multiple axes at once: `a.sum((0,2))`.

Comment: @CiananSims, I didn't see the correct answer here. Every answer guided me a bit. I mostly used DSM's comment. Although your answer is the closest one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first summation is summing along the columns, which I don't think you want.

```
>>> np.sum(a,axis=1)
array([12, 15, 18],
      [39, 42, 45],
      [66, 69, 72]])
```

Instead, change the axis of the first summation. This will yield the same answer as your matlab code:

```
>>> print np.sum(np.sum(a, axis=0), axis=1)
[99, 126, 153]
```

Comment: Thank you.So numpy sums first the columns and matlab the rows? What are the exact mechanisms?

Comment: `sum(a)` in matlab is equivalent to `a.sum(axis=0)` in NumPy. You're transposing your matrices in matlab before summing them, which is why I have to change the axis to get the same result.

Comment: I prefer not. I thought that helps them to become aligned. So if I don't do that what would be the correct code? `a.sum(a.sum(axis=1),axis=1)`??

Comment: Play with it until you get the answer you're looking for. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the problem is that the result of `np.sum(a, axis=1)` is a 2-dimensional array.  If you then try to sum that along axis=2, you'll get the error you see because a 2d array only has axes 0 and 1.

e.g.:

```
>>> a = np.ones((3,3,3))
>>> np.sum(a, axis=1)
array([[ 3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.]])
>>> np.sum(a, axis=1).shape
(3, 3)
>>> np.sum(np.sum(a, axis=1), axis=1)
array([ 9.,  9.,  9.])
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still doesn't give the right answer. I will update my question with a better example now.